# I need to know, how can I add many URLs to the windows hosts file?

Tags: windows, dns, hosts

I want to block DNS requests in my computer such as login.live.com, fs.windows.com, …, etc.

Basically, I'll change the settings

But I want to know How I add many URLs to the windows hosts file.
(I have many URLs to block, about 1000 URLs in text file)

Answer (score 0):

The hosts file contains hostnames, not URLs.

Run Notepad As Administrator and edit `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`
Each line you add should be an IP address (e.g. a dummy one or 127.0.0.1 foor the loopback IP), followed by whitespace (space(s), tab(s)), followed by a hostname.

This will indeed prevent lookups in DNS for A records.

But are you sure this is how you want to do it?
There may be better methods, like using a filtering proxy for example.